# error measure predictions hmm

Tags: hidden-markov-model, mse

I would like to compare the performance of an hmm with other different models (Artificial Neural Networks or Random Forests) in which I used mean squared error. As with HMMs it is normally given the log probability, Would it be correct to generate samples (with a fixed init seed) from the HMM model obtained and then calculate the MSE in respect to the true values?

Comment: What would you do with that MSE?  If you were to compute a similar MSE for predictions from the other models, what would it tell you, *given that the true model is the HMM in the first place?*

Comment: Thanks for your answer whuber, I was thinking in terms of obtaining the MSE between the HMM generated samples and a left out sequence (test set) as the predict method of the library I am using will only give me the hidden states sequence. Then,  I would to compare this MSE with the MSEs obtained on the other models, as in those other methods I can directly calculate the MSE between the predicted sequence and the true values. My aim is to evaluate which of the three models would be performing better. Is this a wrong approach? I am quite new to all this...